# How to display audio visualization in VLC while playing video?

Tags: audio, video, vlc

I've tried enabling all of the entries in Audio → Visualizations, but they don't show up. Disabling the video track didn't help either.

Running VLC 2.1.5 Rincewind on Awesome WM.

Comment: Do the other visualizations also fail? (eg, Scope, etc)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds First, that is not the proper way to talk to your fellow users, [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/203101). Second, this question is perfectly [on topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here since it is about an "Application packaged in *nix distributions". Take the time to learn the scope of a site before telling people what to do. Third, this is completely off topic on [so].

Comment: @edwardtorvalds It's not about a missing "please" - it's about irrelevant comments. There's already a system in place to get rid of off topic questions: flagging and (if you have access to it) close votes. Case in point, I'll try to remember to delete this comment shortly.

Comment: @barrycarter Yep, updated question.